# How to open my app by a link in a new tab?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, deep-linking

I'm adding deep linking to my app, i'm using uni_links https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links.
everything works fine but the app opens in the same tab as the link, and not in a new one.
how can I make the app open in another tab?

example in the image: the app opens on the hangouts tab, instead of go back to it's own tab.
[image: example in the image: the app opens on the hangouts tab, instead of go back to it's own tab.]

Answer (score 0):

You should use flutter [dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=CjwKCAjwtdeFBhBAEiwAKOIy57adt_m9V7NrRdYVq3YTpHHijY7jzch63ihABMkqQ2ZA2kqmMvWxQRoCTakQAvD_BwE)

You should read this documentation [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)

current veriosn: `firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.4`

Example:

```dart
// Copyright 2019 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Dynamic Links Example',
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/': (BuildContext context) => _MainScreen(),
      '/helloworld': (BuildContext context) => _DynamicLinkScreen(),
    },
  ));
}

class _MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<_MainScreen> {
  String? _linkMessage;
  bool _isCreatingLink = false;
  String _testString =
      'To test: long press link and then copy and click from a non-browser '
      "app. Make sure this isn't being tested on iOS simulator and iOS xcode "
      'is properly setup. Look at firebase_dynamic_links/README.md for more '
      'details.';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks();
  }

  Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData? dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri? deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {
        // ignore: unawaited_futures
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });

    final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri? deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      // ignore: unawaited_futures
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _createDynamicLink(bool short) async {
    setState(() {
      _isCreatingLink = true;
    });

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://cx4k7.app.goo.gl',
      link: Uri.parse('https://dynamic.link.example/helloworld'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'io.flutter.plugins.firebasedynamiclinksexample',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
        shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.google.FirebaseCppDynamicLinksTestApp.dev',
        minimumVersion: '0',
      ),
    );

    Uri url;
    if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await parameters.buildUrl();
    }

    setState(() {
      _linkMessage = url.toString();
      _isCreatingLink = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Dynamic Links Example'),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: !_isCreatingLink
                          ? () => _createDynamicLink(false)
                          : null,
                      child: const Text('Get Long Link'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: !_isCreatingLink
                          ? () => _createDynamicLink(true)
                          : null,
                      child: const Text('Get Short Link'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    if (_linkMessage != null) {
                      await launch(_linkMessage!);
                    }
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: _linkMessage));
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      const SnackBar(content: Text('Copied Link!')),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    _linkMessage ?? '',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(_linkMessage == null ? '' : _testString)
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DynamicLinkScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Hello World DeepLink'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Hello, World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm looking for a solution without firebase

Comment: try checking this link [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)